# ActiveRecord connection warning. (Database connections will not be closed automatically)

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I'm trying to create a little app with Sinatra and ActiveRecord (3.2.3).

This is how my main file looks like:

```
require "sinatra"
require "sinatra/reloader"
require "active_record"
...

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter:  'sqlite3',
  database: 'db.sqlite3',
  host:     'localhost',
)

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end

get('/') { ... }
get('/posts') { ... }
...
```

It works, but sometimes I get a warning in console:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Database connections will not be closed
>   automatically, please close your database connection at the end of the
>   thread by calling `close` on your connection.  For example:
>   ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close'

When warning occurs it's takes a long time before page refreshes.
I don't understand where I should close connection. I've tried to put  `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close` at the bottom of file, but it doesn't help.

*update:*

I forgot to mention that I also use sinatra/reloader plugin from [sinatra-contrib](https://github.com/xnvrmind/sinatra-contrib) gem to look at effect without restarting server.

```
require "sinatra/reloader"
```

If I comment it out then the problem disappears. But anyway, I'm wondering how to get rid of the problem without disabling reloader.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add a middleware to your stack.
Just add this line to your config.ru rack up file:

```
use ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
```

Found the answer here: https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/59

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer did not work for me in Sinatra on Thin (threaded mode). Instead I used:

```
after do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close
end
```

Comment: I found the same to be true for me. Anyone know why this is the case? For the people that did get this to work, what were you using for a server?

Comment: This answer worked on a sinatra application with a db_pool of 10 running on puma.

Answer (score 1):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.remove_connection
```

Works fine for me and is listed in the docs.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This does not qualifies as an answer and probably should be a comment.

Comment: @Adam http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord/5.1.0/ActiveRecord/ConnectionHandling#remove_connection-instance_method - the method is to be called when the database is no longer required.

Comment: @Weary Adventurer Sorry if this was inappropriate. I was focussing on the author's remark that the connection_close method did nothing, and found this to be the correct way of manually closing connections. Kinda overlooked that they wanted an automatic solution

Comment: Check out StackOverflow's guide How To Write A Good Answer in the Help tab.