# Hunting down: DEPRECATION WARNING: Database connections will not be closed automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got this trace and no idea how to trace down the cause for this. this is popping up during tests running. Any ideas on how to proceed?

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Database connections will not be closed automatically, please close your
database connection at the end of the thread by calling `close` on your
connection.  For example: ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close
. (called from mon_synchronize at /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211)
/home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:212:in `block in clear_stale_cached_connections!'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:210:in `each'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:210:in `clear_stale_cached_connections!'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:274:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:61:in `call'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__1441209721629762293__call__222931449678172199__callbacks'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/airbrake-3.1.6/lib/airbrake/rack.rb:41:in `call'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/airbrake-3.1.6/lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:134:in `call'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:64:in `block in call'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in `each'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in `call'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-1.1.3/lib/capybara/server.rb:17:in `call'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/gaul/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Answer (score 3):

Well the working solution is :

```
after do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close
end
```

You can have a look at this question

[ActiveRecord connection warning. (Database connections will not be closed automatically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191531/activerecord-connection-warning-database-connections-will-not-be-closed-automa)

Comment: as i am using rails i doubt that that is the right way to so this, rails should do that for me using the connection management middleware

Comment: i already read this. i'm not using threads in my rails code. maybe some gems (maybe capybara) do use them?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this the solution for anyone that gets this problem, but I believe I figured it out in my own app.

Scenario: Some feature tests (using rspec and capybara) were causing this warning to appear, although the tests were passing.

Problem: Test was loading a page which then called to the controller with ajax, and that rendered back with a couple partials rendered_to_string. One of the partials was throwing an error, but the test was only looking for the appearance of something else, which was not part of that partial. So the test passed.

We need better tests of this particular method, and also, it should be doing fewer things. But this was the cause of my issue, and I only saw it by tailing test.log while I ran my tests.

Comment: tailing the logs was a great idea.  I had a large JS page making several calls.  Noticed several 500 errors.  After addressing the 500 errors, the deprecation errors went away.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as Dominik and I haven't been able to resolve it.

Here are some thoughts:

- First of all, I'm not using any Threads in my code.
- I'm blaming VanityUrls because once the page loads, I kept looking to log/test.log and there were a bunch of images calls that fall into the Vanity route. My guess is that every request spawn a thread ? I don't have any arguments to verify this is happening.
- Having this in mind, I got rid of some images and KIND OF work. I keep getting the Database Warning, but the following tests are working perfectly. In the past, the following tests would fail because AR wouldn't be able to spawn a new connection for the test :(
- I thought it was New Relic, Capybara, Capybara Webkit, AirBrake. I updated those. Still getting the warning.
- Don't know what else to do.