# ActiveRecord execute SQL need to close connection? DEPRECATION WARNING: Database connections will not be closed automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

First off, I am using Rails 3.2 on Puma (but with MRI), and am not doing any explicit threading by hand.

I am in places using the `execute` method, like `MyModel.connection.execute` or I know `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` can do the same thing since all connections are to the same DB for me right now.

I recently started seeing

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Database connections will not be closed automatically, please close your database connection at the end of the thread by calling `close` on your connection. For example ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close
```

This seems self-explanatory, but I can find very little information on it online, mostly about using ActiveRecord with Sinatra (ex [ActiveRecord connection warning. (Database connections will not be closed automatically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191531/activerecord-connection-warning-database-connections-will-not-be-closed-automa)).

I read this:

http://blog.daniel-azuma.com/archives/216

which suggests that Rack middleware does it for me as long as the DB execute transaction is done in a controller (if I understand correctly). Does this mean transactions done elsewhere (such as a model, or decorator - they're useful in many places, so I don't want to put them right in a single controller) must be explicitly closed? Even if it's a model method that does it which was called from a controller, ex:

```
class MyController
  def show
    MyModel.do_execute_sql_stuff
  end
end

class MyModel
  def self.do_execute_sql_stuff
    connection.execute("WHATEVER;")
  end
end
```

Do I need to explicitly close here? If so, should I use `MyModel.connection.close` or `MyModel.clear_active_connections!` as the article suggests? Maybe because English is not my first language, but that method sounds dangerous! And how do I go do it?

```
conn = MyModel.connection
result = conn.execute("STUFF")
do_stuff_with(result)
conn.close |or| MyModel.clear_active_connections!
```

Like that?

What about when using `find_by_sql`? Will it return the connection to the pool, or do I have to explicitly do that?

EDIT: Strangely, I only see this in my production logs. Not on development, nor staging (which should be identical to production).

Answer (score 4):

In This case You need to close your connection manually.

After running your script, you can close it Manually like this.

```
after do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close
end
```

Comment: In which case is that? When doing it from the model? Decorator? Helper? This isn't a one off script, though, this is running continuously...

Comment: You can make a method in model and call it at the end of your execution code where you want to close the connection. That Method have above code so whenever it is been called, connection can be closed.

Comment: What I'm asking though is _when_ do I need to do this - when querying from the model? From a decorator? From a helper? You say "and call it at the end of your execution code" - which execution code is that?

Comment: Please try using querying from model. It should not be in decorator or somewhere else. you should write this in model only. Let me know if this works.