# How do I reuse connections in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I was playing around with Sinatra and ActiveRecord when I found that a connections are not reused automatically by this simple API.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby                                                                                  

require 'sinatra'
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
adapter:  'sqlite3',
database: 'newsletter.db'
)

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :subscribers do |t|
    t.string :email
    t.timestamps
  end
end

class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, presence: true
end

class Newsletter < Sinatra::Base

  set :server, :thin

  get '/subscribers/:email' do
    s = Subscriber.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if s == nil
      status 404
    else
      content_type 'application/json'
      s.to_json
    end
  end

  post '/subscribers/:email' do
    Subscriber.create(email: params[:email])
  end

end

Newsletter.run!
```

The API returns either a subscriber or a 404 the first 5 times I GET a subscriber. The 6th time I get a timeout. After each of the first 5 GETs, there is one more read+write file descriptor open for `newsletter.db`. I would expect there to be only one all the time.

How do I tell ActiveRecord to reuse a connection?

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191531/activerecord-connection-warning-database-connections-will-not-be-closed-automa?rq=1

Comment: By looking at that answer, I eventually found that calling `ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!` works for me. I did try  `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close` and found that that way I close the connection instead of return the connection to the connection pool. I did not try the `config.ru` approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of cleaning connections is to call [`ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionHandler.html#method-i-clear_active_connections-21) after each use of `Subscriber.find_by_email` and `Subscriber.create`, like so.

```
after do
    ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!
end
```

[Somewhere else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675879/activerecordconnectiontimeouterror), some people suggest using middleware `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement`. That does not work in Thin because Thin starts processing each request in a thread and finishes processing the request in another thread. `ConnectionManagement` only returns to the pool those connections that are active for the current thread and Thin applies `ConnectionManagement` in the second thread instead of the first.

**EDIT:**

I made an explanation of why using middleware `ActiveRecord::Connectionadapters::ConnectionManagement` won't work with Thin in threaded mode, which you can find [here](http://ruslanledesma.com/2016/04/23/release-connections-thin-and-active-record.html).

**2016.05.18 EDIT:**

I followed up this issue with Thin author and this issue is not resolved after issue [307](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/issues/307).