# Replacing ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement in ActiveRecord 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

We are upgrading a [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) application from [ActiveRecord 4](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/4-2-stable/activerecord) to ActiveRecord 5. Previously we had this line:

`use ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement`

This is because connections were not being cleaned up after requests completed. Here is prior SO discussion on this topic:

- [ActiveRecord connection warning. (Database connections will not be closed automatically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191531/activerecord-connection-warning-database-connections-will-not-be-closed-automa)
- [ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675879/activerecordconnectiontimeouterror)

Starting with ActiveRecord 5, this line no longer works. This [conversation in the rails project states](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26947):

> This was removed in favor of Executor and Reloader APIs. That
>   middleware that was removed were not part of the public API.  If you
>   want to use that outside Rails you need to make one.

Does this mean that, if someone is to use ActiveRecord 5 with Sinatra, connections will be again 'leaked' or left un-returned to the pool after a request, unless the developer re-creates the now-removed middleware?

In the Sinatra example, is it therefore now the case that we need to include this line in ActiveRecord 5?

```
after do
  ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!
end
```

That is the implication on the linked-to thread, but I want to get a definite answer I can take back to my dev team.

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: I did not; we are continuing to call that line in AR5 in the manner specified above.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are correct, the `ConnectionManagement` middleware has been removed from ActiveRecord 5 (PR [#23807](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/23807)), so you will need to replicate similar functionality when setting up ActiveRecord outside of Rails. There are several ways to do this:

#### 1. `ConnectionManagement` Rack middleware

The [`ConnectionManagement` class](https://github.com/matthewd/rails/blob/b83c097a3c6b01870e58c4da01702c2e4996ca0e/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb#L955-L973) is not very complicated. You can copy and paste the implementation somewhere in your local application, and include it as usual into your Rack middleware stack:

```
class ConnectionManagement
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    testing = env['rack.test']

    status, headers, body = @app.call(env)
    proxy = ::Rack::BodyProxy.new(body) do
      ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections! unless testing
    end
    [status, headers, proxy]
  rescue Exception
    ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections! unless testing
    raise
  end
end

use ConnectionManagement
```

#### 2. (Sinatra-specific) connection-management `after` hook

Within a Sinatra app, the block you suggested should work:

```
after do
  ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!
end
```

Note that this is also the approach [currently used](https://github.com/janko-m/sinatra-activerecord/commit/85e35341175e0b47e49b3d71ec3bf4fc5e61009d#diff-a8d61b0c6c1526535937f4851a83d8b0R33) by the [`sinatra-activerecord`](https://github.com/janko-m/sinatra-activerecord) integration gem to support ActiveRecord 5 (see issue [#73](https://github.com/janko-m/sinatra-activerecord/issues/73)).

#### 3. `ActionDispatch::Executor` Rack middleware

Finally, you can use the same code Rails is now using for ActiveRecord connection management by adding `ActionDispatch::Executor` into your Rack middleware stack, and calling [`ActiveRecord::QueryCache#install_executor_hooks`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3c785bdceed4bdf67708197aa687ced6728d77f3/activerecord/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb#L43) to insert the hook used to clear ActiveRecord connections:

```
require 'action_dispatch/middleware/executor'
use ActionDispatch::Executor, ActiveSupport::Executor
ActiveRecord::QueryCache.install_executor_hooks
```

Comment: Woohoo thank you so much for the detailed and definitive answer!

Comment: I've wrapped up `class ConnectionManagement` in this gem: https://github.com/ioquatix/activerecord-rack

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam This question is specifically about using ActiveRecord 5 in a _non-Rails_ environment (more specifically, Sinatra); ActiveRecord connection management is already built-in to Rails so no extra code is needed in that case.

Comment: This isn't the place to discuss an unrelated Rails connection-pool question- post it separately to StackOverflow and someone might help answer it for you.

Comment: In ActiveRecord 6 for query cache to work I had also to add: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_handlers = { writing: ActiveRecord::Base.default_connection_handler }` before `establish_connection`.